# Spring unable to convert from String to RSAPublicKey/RSAPrivateKey when add a new dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, type-conversion, flyway

I have a microservice with Spring Security and I have the contents of the private and public keys in application.yml (please don't judge me). I also have a @ConfigurationProperties file with this properties. The service works fine, internally RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor does the convertions from String to RSAPublicKey/RSAPrivateKey respectively.

The problem is that when I add the flyway-core dependency in my pom.xml. Spring is unable to do the conversion. This microservice is not mine so I cannot move the keys from properties to files and read it from there.

Do you have any idea what might be happening?

**application.yml**

```
lorem:
  ipsum:
    dolor:
      jwt:
        private-key: |
          -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
          ...
          -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
        public-key: |
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          ...
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

**Property class**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "lorem.ipsum.dolor.jwt")
@Component
class SecurityProperties {

    private RSAPrivateKey privateKey;
    private RSAPublicKey publicKey;
}
```

**Error log**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Failed to bind properties under 'lorem.ipsum.dolor.jwt.public-key' to java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey:
    Property: augcod.security.authentication.jwt.public-key
    Value: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    Origin: class path resource [application-local.yml] - 34:21
    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey]
Action:
Update your application's configuration
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>lorem.ipsum.dolor</groupId>
    <artifactId>sit-amet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.66</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.66</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To support Junit 4 tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-deps</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the spring version and flyway-core version from the pom.xml? Edit: Or the whole pom.xml

Comment: Sure. I just edited the post.

Comment: I would use `man dependency:tree` to see if flyway is bringing in any transitive dependencies which might be causing the problem.

Comment: Flyway don't have any transitive dependency. At least this is what the command showed me
```
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.16:provided
[INFO] +- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:7.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:test
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like property converters are not loaded for some reason. I believe it's bug in the the Spring Boot auto configuration.

If you want to solve it immediately, then you can just implement the converters on your own. Just use the same Spring classes.

Something like this:

```
package lorem.ipsum.dolor.sitamet;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinding;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.converter.RsaKeyConverters;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;

@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class MyPrivateKeyConverter implements Converter<String, RSAPrivateKey> {
    @Override
    public RSAPrivateKey convert(String from) {
        return RsaKeyConverters.pkcs8().convert(new ByteArrayInputStream(from.getBytes()));
    }
}
```

```
package lorem.ipsum.dolor.sitamet;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinding;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.converter.RsaKeyConverters;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class MyPublicKeyConverter implements Converter<String, RSAPublicKey> {
    @Override
    public RSAPublicKey convert(String from) {
        return RsaKeyConverters.x509().convert(new ByteArrayInputStream(from.getBytes()));
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need to specify version of the `flyway-core` in the `pom.xml`. It will be inherited from `spring-boot-starter-parent`.